# Manga about guy transported into strategy video game as a noble

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm trying to find the name of a manga about a guy transported into a strategy video game.

The manga starts with the main character winning the strategy game on the highest difficulty setting, then he gets a notice from the game creators and he is transported into the body of a weak and tyrannical noble who was killed before the game even starts.

Answer (score 3):

This is *[I'm Now an Evil Lord In a World Where Only I Can Level Up](https://myanimelist.net/manga/142163)*.

> Ryuuichi Hasegawa, **the top player in a strategic medieval RPG**, is granted a special "bonus" by the developer and reincarnated into the game world—not as the protagonist, but as **the villainous lord Erhin Eintorian who dies in the prologue!** This means Erhin's survival is a race against time, for his domain is set to be invaded by a hostile foreign power in just one day. ...

The opening goes as described - the protagonist is playing the strategy RPG game as the top player and suddenly gets a notification for an extra mode. He accepts, but nothing immediately happens.

[image: Accepting the game]

He then goes to bed and wakes up in the world of the game as a minor character - there's no mention of his name, but he recognizes the name of the country as one that is promptly destroyed in the prologue.

[image: Discussion of his fate]

Answer (score 2):

This matches "[I became tyrant of a defense game](https://myanimelist.net/manga/153518/Tyrant_of_the_Tower_Defense_Game)".

Protagonist finishes game at highest difficulty and is transported to game's world in tutorial level which is not meant to be survived. Later he meets "in-game assistant" that confesses that he is (kinda?) god of this world and he distributed gamified version of the world in many different worlds. He asks protagonist to reach a good ending.