Manga (probably manhwa or manhua) in which mc becomes an elf that is an NPC city lord in the game he plays
First of all I believe this one is color if my memory is serve.
The mc somehow (reincarnate/suck or whatever) into the game where he is a elf NPC. This NPC is a city lord and when he got into this game it is before open beta of the game he play i believe.
Mc as a NPC has elves army that serve him but they did not like him that much and the only reason they still there at first is because his mother or father (not sure). This comic (will call this cuz I don't want to confuse other since I don't know where it came from) started with Mc try to get stronger cuz there will be war and his city will be the first to fall because this city is in the middle something like that.
Edit more information: In this open beta mc try to impress player to come to his city.
And I think time in game keep flowing not stop when player can't enter. like you play this game when city just started build. beta period end and 5 days later the game open for everyone the city already finished something like that. sorry if this might be confuse

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

I read this on the internet around 2-4 years ago.

Two possibilities here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/278462 . I don't see any mention of elves in either.

The war thing will start after the game is open for everybody I think. But not before or in close beta for sure
